# Selecting a value of a variable from a set of values during object creation in Python

Tags: python

I want to create an instance for the class Player like:

```
myPlayer = Player(name="ABc", level="A")
```

The parameter level  is a string and can have the following values `'A','B', 'C','D','E'`.

How can I limit the user input for the value of level to these specific values?How can I achieve this in Python?

My current program looks like this:

```
class Player:          
    def __init__(self,pname, level):
        self.pname = pname
        self.level = level
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is a `set` match. Ex:

```
class Player(object):
    _valid_levels = {'A','B','C','D','E'}

    def __init__(self, name, level):
        if level not in Player._valid_levels:
            raise ValueError("Level should be {}, got {}".format(Player._valid_levels, level))
        self.name  = name
        self.level = level
```

This will raise a `ValueError` if the user attempts to instantiate a `Player` with an incorrect level. Note this is case sensitive!

Answer (score 1):

You could raise an exception in the case that the level is invalid

```
if level not in "ABCDE":
    raise ValueError('Level must be one of (A, B, C, D, E)')
```

Alternatively if you have access to python3.4+, you could use an enum

```
import enum

class Level(enum.Enum):
    A, B, C, D, E = range(5)
```

and then create players using enum objects

```
Player('MyName', Level.B)
```

Comment: Note the `Enum` solution, by itself, doesn't actually *enforce* the level restriction, it just makes following it less error prone. You'd still have to check it against something.